# Different results for same function when parallel R computation

Tags: r, parallel-processing, system2

I have an issue with invoke an external batch using **system2** function with  **parallel library** under Windows 10, my function execute a external program to read a binary file (must be content in the same folder as example). The issue is myfunction return the right number of rows (35 rows) when is call as simple function  but when parallelized give 4 rows less (31 row).
[Here you can find an example with all files](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kdoqdv5uh1rhr98/AAB86TpgVjVlFQRsTOvmZoipa?dl=0)
(https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kdoqdv5uh1rhr98/AAB86TpgVjVlFQRsTOvmZoipa?dl=0)
my function is as following:

## run function

```
file_to_read<-"crop@seasonal$d.UED"
library(parallel)    
cl <- makeCluster(2)
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(base))
seq_along_path_index<-seq_along(all_cells$V1)
list_results<-parLapply(cl,file_to_read,
                      myfunction)) #return 31
stopCluster(cl)
#simple call
list_results2<-myfunction(file_to_read) #return 35
```

## My function is define as:

```
myfunction<- function(file_to_read) {
    
setwd('G:/Dropbox/Public/Example')
command<-"./UED_collate.exe"
arg1<-'./crop@seasonal$d.TDF'
crop<- base::system2(command, 
                                 args=c(arg1 , file_to_read,
                                        "--captions:", "state", "site",        "cycle", "crop"),
                                 stdout = TRUE, wait=TRUE) 
n_row<-length(crop)

return(n_row)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks I change it, still having same issued

Answer (score 0):

It may come from the fact that a data frame is also a list.
For example, when you use `unlist(list(iris, iris))`, you get a numeric vector of size 1500.
Instead, try to use `unlist` with `recursive = FALSE` if you want a list with all data frame columns, or use `do.call("rbind", list(iris, iris))` instead of `unlist(list(iris, iris))` if you want the data frames to be appended by rows.